# libgit2 how do i commit a file successfully?

Tags: c, git, libgit2

how do i get commit to work AFTER the initial commit using libgit2 as i have checked out and tried all of the other posts related to implimenting git commit using libgit2 but all of them seem to fail with either SIGSEGV On the commit or give "error: Could not create the initial commit (-15) (failed to create commit: current tip is not the first parent)"

full source code available at http://github.com/mgood7123/Git

## UPDATE: had to take down the repo for a while to:

#### remove my username and password from the source files

#### add a way for users to use there own username and password

#### allow users to define a username and password to use as the default instead of asking every time

#### should be back up now

My goal is to impliment this

```
#!./Files/bash-4.4.0
git config --global user.email "null@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "null"
git add --all
git commit -m -a
git push --force origin master
```

and eventually this

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $1' -- --all
```

with libgit2 as a minimal backup system since native binaries cannot be used (as ios does notallow this) so i cannot just compile git itself from source

UPDATE: i have fixed the crash and it commits successfully how ever the file is still in "Changes to be committed:"

```
push> touch k
push> ggitnadd k
ggitnadd : Command not found.
push> git add k
git_libgit2_features() = 15
git_libgit2_init() = 1
called
add 'k'
push> git commit k
git_libgit2_init() = 1
git_repository_head_unborn(repo) = 0
aquiring reference
git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_id,repo,"HEAD") = 0 (none)
looking up reference
git_commit_lookup(&parent,repo,&parent_id) = 0 (none)
attemting to commit
git_commit_tree(&tree,parent) = 0 (none)
ret = 0 (none)
commit sucessfull
push> git status
# On branch 
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   gfd
#   new file:   k
#   new file:   te
#
push> git commit -a
git_libgit2_init() = 1
git_repository_head_unborn(repo) = 0
aquiring reference
git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_id,repo,"HEAD") = 0 (none)
looking up reference
git_commit_lookup(&parent,repo,&parent_id) = 0 (none)
attemting to commit
git_commit_tree(&tree,parent) = 0 (none)
ret = 0 (none)
commit sucessfull
push> git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   gfd
#   new file:   k
#   new file:   te
#
push>
```

yet it sucesfully commits if i commit to a bare repository

```
Git> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/CCR/UserFiles/Mobile C/Git/.git
Git> git add -A
git_libgit2_features() = 15
git_libgit2_init() = 1
called
add 'git.c'
called
add 'git/common.c.h'
called
add 'git/common.h'
called
add 'git/git.h'
called
add 'git/git_add.h'
called
add 'git/git_clone.h'
called
add 'git/git_commit.h'
called
add 'git/git_config.h'
called
add 'git/git_curl.h'
called
add 'git/git_hook_config.h'
called
add 'git/git_init.h'
called
add 'git/git_macros.h'
called
add 'git/git_push.h'
called
add 'git/git_remote.h'
called
add 'git/git_stat.h'
called
add 'git/git_tests.h'
called
add 'git/githeader.h'
called
add 'git/strbuf.h'
called
add 'gitcommit'
called
add 'gitremove'
called
add 'tests/push/'
Git> git status
# On branch Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   git.c
#   new file:   git/common.c.h
#   new file:   git/common.h
#   new file:   git/git.h
#   new file:   git/git_add.h
#   new file:   git/git_clone.h
#   new file:   git/git_commit.h
#   new file:   git/git_config.h
#   new file:   git/git_curl.h
#   new file:   git/git_hook_config.h
#   new file:   git/git_init.h
#   new file:   git/git_macros.h
#   new file:   git/git_push.h
#   new file:   git/git_remote.h
#   new file:   git/git_stat.h
#   new file:   git/git_tests.h
#   new file:   git/githeader.h
#   new file:   git/strbuf.h
#   new file:   gitcommit
#   new file:   gitremove
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   tests/push/
Git> git commit -a
git_libgit2_init() = 1
git_repository_head_unborn(repo) = 1
looking up tree
attemting to commit
Git> git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   tests/push/
Git>
```

commit.h

```
int gitprefix(commit) (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    git_repository *repo;
    git_signature *sig;
    git_index *index;
    git_oid tree_id, commit_id;
    git_tree *tree;
    
    pi(git_libgit2_init());

    if (git_repository_open(&repo, ".")) {
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository");
    }
    
    /** First use the config to initialize a commit signature for the user. */
        
    if (git_signature_default(&sig, repo) < 0) {
        if (git_signature_new(&sig, "null","null@gmail.com",0,0) < 0) {
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Unable to create a commit signature.\n%s",
              "Perhaps 'user.name' and 'user.email' are not set");
        }
    }

    /* Now let's create an empty tree for this commit */

    if (git_repository_index(&index, repo) < 0) {
        git_index_free(index);
        git_signature_free(sig);
        git_repository_free(repo);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository index", NULL);
    }

    /**
     * Outside of this example, you could call git_index_add_bypath()
     * here to put actual files into the index.  For our purposes, we'll
     * leave it empty for now.
     */

    if (git_index_write_tree(&tree_id, index) < 0) {
        git_index_free(index);
        git_tree_free(tree);
        git_signature_free(sig);
        git_repository_free(repo);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Unable to write initial tree from index", NULL);
    }

    git_index_free(index);
    
    pi(git_repository_head_unborn(repo))
    if(git_repository_head_unborn(repo) == 1) {
        puts("looking up tree");
        if (git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &tree_id) < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not look up initial tree", NULL);
        }
    
        /**
         * Ready to create the initial commit.
         *
         * Normally creating a commit would involve looking up the current
         * HEAD commit and making that be the parent of the initial commit,
         * but here this is the first commit so there will be no parent.
         */
        
        puts("attemting to commit");
        int ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "Initial commit", tree, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not create the initial commit (%d)", ret);
        }
    } else if (git_repository_head_unborn(repo) == 0) {
        git_oid parent_id;
        git_commit *parent;
        // Get HEAD as a commit object to use as the parent of the commit 
        puts("aquiring reference");
        giterr(git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_id, repo, "HEAD"));
        puts("looking up reference");
        giterr(git_commit_lookup(&parent, repo, &parent_id));
        puts("attemting to commit");
        giterr(git_commit_tree(&tree, parent));
        int ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "-a", tree, 1, parent, NULL);
        giterr(ret);
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not create the initial commit (%d)", ret);
        }
        puts("commit sucessfull");
        
    }
    
    /** Clean up so we don't leak memory. */

    git_tree_free(tree);
    git_signature_free(sig);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

commit2.h (didnt work)

```
int gitprefix(commit2) (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    git_repository *repo;
    git_signature *sig;
    git_index *index;
    git_oid tree_id, commit_id;
    git_tree *tree = NULL;
    
    pi(git_libgit2_init());

    if (git_repository_open(&repo, ".")) {
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository");
    }
    
    /** First use the config to initialize a commit signature for the user. */
        
    if (git_signature_default(&sig, repo) < 0) {
        if (git_signature_new(&sig, "null","null@gmail.com",0,0) < 0) {
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Unable to create a commit signature.\n%s",
              "Perhaps 'user.name' and 'user.email' are not set");
        }
    }

    pi(git_repository_head_unborn(repo))
    if(git_repository_head_unborn(repo) == 1) {
        /* Now let's create an empty tree for this commit */

        if (git_repository_index(&index, repo) < 0) {
            git_index_free(index);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not open repository index", NULL);
        }
    
        /**
         * Outside of this example, you could call git_index_add_bypath()
         * here to put actual files into the index.  For our purposes, we'll
         * leave it empty for now.
         */
    
        if (git_index_write_tree(&tree_id, index) < 0) {
            git_index_free(index);
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Unable to write initial tree from index", NULL);
        }
    
        git_index_free(index);
        
        puts("looking up tree");
        if (git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &tree_id) < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not look up initial tree", NULL);
        }
    
        /**
         * Ready to create the initial commit.
         *
         * Normally creating a commit would involve looking up the current
         * HEAD commit and making that be the parent of the initial commit,
         * but here this is the first commit so there will be no parent.
         */
        
        puts("attemting to commit");
        int ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "Initial commit", tree, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not create the initial commit (%d)", ret);
        }
    } else if (git_repository_head_unborn(repo) == 0) {
        /* Now let's create an empty tree for this commit */
        
        if (git_repository_index(&index, repo) < 0) {
            git_index_free(index);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not open repository index", NULL);
        }
    
        /**
         * Outside of this example, you could call git_index_add_bypath()
         * here to put actual files into the index.  For our purposes, we'll
         * leave it empty for now.
         */
        
        /* Overwrite the index contents with those of a tree */
        giterr(git_revparse_single((git_object**)&tree, repo, "HEAD~^{tree}"));
        giterr(git_index_read_tree(index, tree));
        
        /* Write the index contents to the ODB as a tree */
        giterr(git_index_write_tree(&tree_id, index));
        
        /* In-memory indexes can write trees to any repo */
        giterr(git_index_write_tree_to(&tree_id, index, repo));
    
        git_index_free(index);
        
        git_oid parent_id;
        git_commit *parent;
        git_commit *parent2;
        // Get HEAD as a commit object to use as the parent of the commit 
        puts("aquiring reference");
        giterr(git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_id, repo, "HEAD"));
        puts("looking up reference");
        giterr(git_commit_lookup(&parent, repo, &parent_id));
        puts("attemting to commit");
        giterr(git_commit_tree(&tree, parent));
        int ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "-a", tree, 1, parent, NULL);
        //int git_commit_parent(git_commit **out, const git_commit *commit, unsigned int n);
        //int ret = git_commit_parent(&parent2, parent, 0);
        giterr(ret);
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not create the commit (%d)", ret);
        }
        puts("commit sucessfull");
        
    }
    
    /** Clean up so we don't leak memory. */

    git_tree_free(tree);
    git_signature_free(sig);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

add.h

```
int gitprefix(add) (int argc, char** argv)
{
    git_index_matched_path_cb matched_cb = &pmatched_cb;
    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    git_index *index;
    git_strarray array = {0};
    int options = 0, count = 0;
    struct print_payload payload = {0};

    pi(git_libgit2_features());
    pi(git_libgit2_init());

    gitret(gitprefix(parse_optsA)(&options, &count, argc, argv));

    gitprefix(init_array)(&array, argc-count, argv+count);

    if (git_repository_open(&repo, ".")) {
        git_repository_free(repo);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository");
    }
    
    if (git_repository_index(&index, repo)) {
        git_index_free(index);
        git_repository_free(repo);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository index");
    }

    payload.options = options;
    payload.repo = repo;

    git_index_add_all(index, &array, GIT_INDEX_ADD_DEFAULT, matched_cb, &payload);
    git_index_update_all(index, &array, matched_cb, &payload);

    git_index_write(index);
    git_index_free(index);
    git_repository_free(repo);

    git_libgit2_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the code for the commit function (as the full code is split into several files)

```
#define ps(x) printf("%s = %s\n", #x, x);
#define pi(x) printf("%s = %d\n", #x, x);
#define pp(x) printf("%s = %p\n", #x, x);

#define gitprefix(x) git_libgit_version_2_api_##x


#define giterr(x) { printf("%s = %d (%s)\n", #x, x, giterr_last()?giterr_last()->message:"none"); }

#define giterror(...) { \
    printf("error: " __VA_ARGS__); \
    printf(" (%s)", giterr_last()?giterr_last()->message:"none"); \
    printf("\n"); \
    return -2; \
}

#define giterrorn(...) { \
    printf("error: " __VA_ARGS__); \
    printf(" (%s)", giterr_last()?giterr_last()->message:"none"); \
    printf("\n"); \
    return NULL; \
}

#define gitret(x) { \
    int ret = x ; \
    if (ret) return ret; \
}

int gitprefix(commit) (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    git_repository *repo;
    git_signature *sig;
    git_index *index;
    git_oid tree_id, commit_id;
    git_tree *tree;
    
    pi(git_libgit2_init());

    if (git_repository_open(&repo, ".")) {
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository");
    }
    
    /** First use the config to initialize a commit signature for the user. */
        
    if (git_signature_default(&sig, repo) < 0) {
        if (git_signature_new(&sig, "null","null@gmail.com",0,0) < 0) {
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Unable to create a commit signature.\n%s",
              "Perhaps 'user.name' and 'user.email' are not set");
        }
    }

    /* Now let's create an empty tree for this commit */

    if (git_repository_index(&index, repo) < 0) {
        git_index_free(index);
        git_signature_free(sig);
        git_repository_free(repo);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository index", NULL);
    }

    /**
     * Outside of this example, you could call git_index_add_bypath()
     * here to put actual files into the index.  For our purposes, we'll
     * leave it empty for now.
     */

    if (git_index_write_tree(&tree_id, index) < 0) {
        git_index_free(index);
        git_tree_free(tree);
        git_signature_free(sig);
        git_repository_free(repo);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Unable to write initial tree from index", NULL);
    }

    git_index_free(index);
    
    pi(git_repository_head_unborn(repo))
    if(git_repository_head_unborn(repo) == 1) {
        puts("looking up tree");
        if (git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &tree_id) < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not look up initial tree", NULL);
        }
    
        /**
         * Ready to create the initial commit.
         *
         * Normally creating a commit would involve looking up the current
         * HEAD commit and making that be the parent of the initial commit,
         * but here this is the first commit so there will be no parent.
         */
        
        puts("attemting to commit");
        int ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "Initial commit", tree, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_signature_free(sig);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not create the initial commit (%d)", ret);
        }
    } else if (git_repository_head_unborn(repo) == 0) {
        git_oid parent_id;
        git_commit *parent;
        // Get HEAD as a commit object to use as the parent of the commit 
        puts("aquiring reference");
        giterr(git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_id, repo, "HEAD"));
        puts("looking up reference");
        giterr(git_commit_lookup(&parent, repo, &parent_id));
        puts("attemting to commit");
        // Do the commit
        int ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "-a", tree, 1, parent); // seg faults here, does not seg fault if i remove parent but gives -15
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not create the initial commit (%d)", ret);
        }
        
    }
    
    /** Clean up so we don't leak memory. */

    git_tree_free(tree);
    git_signature_free(sig);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

and the main git.c:

```
#include "git/git.h"

int _main(void);

int rec = 0; // set to 1 to test recursion and stability
int m = 0;
int i = 500;

int main(void)
{
    str_new(path);
    str_new(num);
    str_insert_string(path, path.index, "init ");
    str_insert_int(num, num.index, m);
    str_insert_string(path, path.index, num.string);
    str_insert_string(path, path.index, " --initial-commit");
    _main(num.string, path.string);
    str_free(path)
    str_free(num)
    if (rec == 1) {
    if(m < i) {
        m++;
        main();
    }
    if (m <= i) printf("%d <= %d\n", m, i);
    m--;
    }
    chdir("../");
    return 0;
}

int _main(char * dir, char * init)
{
    git("init a");
    chdir("a");
    git("commit");
    puts("testing");
    git(init);
    chdir(dir);
    git("commit");
    puts("");
    puts("");
    puts("");
    puts("");
    touch("test");
    mkdir("b",0777);
    touch("b/l");
    git("add -A");
    git("stat a/0");
    git("commit");
    git("status");
    chdir("../../");
    puts("testing done");
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output of the full command:

```
self> git
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/CCR/UserFiles/Mobile C/Git/self/a/.git
git_libgit2_init() = 3
git_repository_head_unborn(repo) = 1
looking up tree
attemting to commit
testing
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/CCR/UserFiles/Mobile C/Git/self/a/0/.git
git_libgit2_init() = 3
git_repository_head_unborn(repo) = 1
looking up tree
attemting to commit




git_libgit2_features() = 15
git_libgit2_init() = 3
File Path: b/l
    Stage: 0
 Blob SHA: e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
File Mode: 0100644
File Size: 0 bytes
Dev/Inode: 0/1962460
  UID/GID: 501/501
    ctime: 1532334385
    mtime: 1532334385

File Path: test
    Stage: 0
 Blob SHA: e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
File Mode: 0100644
File Size: 0 bytes
Dev/Inode: 0/1962458
  UID/GID: 501/501
    ctime: 1532334385
    mtime: 1532334385

git_libgit2_init() = 3
git_repository_head_unborn(repo) = 0
aquiring reference
git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_id,repo,"HEAD") = 0 (none)
looking up reference
git_commit_lookup(&parent,repo,&parent_id) = 0 (none)
attemting to commit
SIGSEGV on thread : 1090547712
0>
```

Minimal compilable example:

```
#include <git2.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define giterr(x) { printf("%s = %d (%s)\n", #x, x, giterr_last()?giterr_last()->message:"none"); }


#define giterror(...) { \
    printf("error: " __VA_ARGS__); \
    printf(" (%s)", giterr_last()?giterr_last()->message:"none"); \
    printf("\n"); \
    return -2; \
}

int main(void)
{
    int ret = 0, retg = 0;
    git_repository *repo;
    git_signature *sig;
    git_index *index;
    git_oid tree_id, commit_id;
    git_tree *tree;
    git_oid parent_id;
    git_commit *parent;
    ret = git_libgit2_init();
    giterr(ret)
    ret = chdir("a/0");
    giterr(ret)
    ret = git_repository_open(&repo, ".");
    giterr(ret)
    if (ret < 0) {
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository");
    }
    ret = git_signature_default(&sig, repo);
    giterr(ret)
    if (ret < 0) {
        puts("Failed to obtain default signature, attempting to create new signature");
        ret = git_signature_new(&sig, "null","null@gmail.com",0,0);
        giterr(ret)
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_signature_free(sig); // returns void
            git_repository_free(repo); // returns void
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Unable to create a commit signature.\n%s",
              "Perhaps 'user.name' and 'user.email' are not set");
        }
    }
    ret = git_repository_index(&index, repo);
    giterr(ret)
    if (ret < 0) {
        git_index_free(index); // returns void
        git_signature_free(sig); // returns void
        git_repository_free(repo); // returns void
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository index", NULL);
    }

    ret = git_index_write_tree(&tree_id, index);
    giterr(ret)
    if (ret < 0) {
        git_index_free(index); // returns void
        git_tree_free(tree); // returns void
        git_signature_free(sig); // returns void
        git_repository_free(repo); // returns void
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Unable to write initial tree from index", NULL);
    }
    git_index_free(index); // returns void
    retg = git_repository_head_unborn(repo);
    giterr(retg)
    if (retg == 1) {
        ret = git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &tree_id);
        giterr(ret)
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree); // returns void
            git_signature_free(sig); // returns void
            git_repository_free(repo); // returns void
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not look up initial tree", NULL);
        }
        ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "Initial commit", tree, 0);
        giterr(ret)
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree); // returns void
            git_signature_free(sig); // returns void
            git_repository_free(repo); // returns void
            git_libgit2_shutdown(); // returns void
            giterror("Could not create the initial commit (%d)", ret);
        }
    }
    else if (retg == 0) {
        ret = git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_id, repo, "HEAD");
        giterr(ret)
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_tree_free(tree); // returns void
            git_signature_free(sig); // returns void
            git_repository_free(repo); // returns void
            git_libgit2_shutdown(); // returns void
            giterror("Cannot convert reference to id (%d)", ret);
        }
        ret = git_commit_lookup(&parent, repo, &parent_id);
        giterr(ret)
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_commit_free(parent); // returns void
            git_tree_free(tree); // returns void
            git_signature_free(sig); // returns void
            git_repository_free(repo); // returns void
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Cannot look up commit (%d)", ret);
        }
        puts("committing");
        giterr(git_commit_tree(&tree, parent));
        ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "-a", tree, 1, parent, NULL);
        puts("committed");
        giterr(ret)
        if (ret < 0) {
            git_commit_free(parent); // returns void
            git_tree_free(tree); // returns void
            git_signature_free(sig); // returns void
            git_repository_free(repo); // returns void
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
            giterror("Could not create the initial commit (%d)", ret);
        }
        // seg fault
    }
    ret = chdir("../../");
    giterr(ret)
    git_tree_free(tree);
    git_signature_free(sig);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    ret = git_libgit2_shutdown();
    giterr(ret)
    return 0;
}
```

Its output

```
ret = 3 (none)
ret = 0 (none)
ret = 0 (none)
ret = -3 (config value 'user.name' was not found)
Failed to obtain default signature, attempting to create new signature
ret = 0 (config value 'user.name' was not found)
ret = 0 (config value 'user.name' was not found)
ret = 0 (none)
retg = 0 (none)
ret = 0 (none)
ret = 0 (none)
committing
ret = 0 (none)
committed
ret = 0 (none)
ret = 0 (none)
```

Answer (score 1):

At least from your example, you don't seem to be passing any parent to your 2nd commit. As per the [docs](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/commit/git_commit_create_v), you're supposed to pass a variable-argument list of `git_commit` objects.

So the correct call is :

```
int ret = git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "-a", tree, 1, parent, NULL);
```

Otherwise you're likely passing stack-garbage to the function, hence the SIGSEGVs and errors.

**Edit:** sorry varargs are hard. I forgot to add the `NULL` sentinel value.

**Edit 2:** here are the results. There are 2 problems with your code (at least the minimally compilable example) :

- you cannot use `giterr_last()` when the library isn't initialized, that will crash hard. Since you usually `git_libgit2_shutdown()` before calling `giterror` you won't survive long.
- you're passing an uninitialized `git_tree` the 2nd time around, since you only perform a lookup in your "unborn" case. That's another crash. Use `git_commit_tree` on your looked up commit.

I do not what IDE you're on, but at least Xcode says this about your crash:

`Assertion failed: (tree && git_tree_owner(tree) == repo), function git_commit_create_v, file /Users/tiennou/Projects/libgit2/src/commit.c, line 231.`

Comment: git_commit_lookup(&parent,repo,&parent_id) = 0 (none)
attemting to commit
SIGSEGV on thread : 1082142720 
0>

Comment: Truthfully, given that your example doesn't compile, I don't think I will be able to help you more. You should investigate the crash with a debugger and see where it actually happens.

Comment: Included a minimal compilable example

Comment: so i need to do this? `else if (retg == 0) /*update initial commit */ { git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_id, repo, "HEAD"); git_commit_lookup(&parent, repo, &parent_id); git_commit_tree(&tree, &commit_id); puts("committing"); git_commit_create_v(&commit_id, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, NULL, "-a", tree, 1, parent, NULL); puts("committed");`

Comment: If the file is stage 0 does that mean it will not be commited and pushed to github unless it is added with git add?